# Python hexidecimal address packing from string

Tags: python, hex, pack

This works correctly:

```
packed = struct.pack('<L',0x7c023a4f)
```

This does not:

```
address = '0x7c023a4f'
packed = struct.pack('<L',address)
```

How do i make this work?
I tried a lot of methods from the binascii library but i cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` to evaluate the string as hex number before packing it:

```
from ast import literal_eval
address = '0x7c023a4f'
packed = struct.pack('<L', literal_eval(address))

packed
# 'O:\x02|'
```

Comment: Thank you. that was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an integer:

```
address = '0x7c023a4f'
packed = struct.pack('<L', int(address, 16))
```